# Please clarify the functionality of this parent-child relationship

Tags: salesforce

I have the answer to this question, but don't understand the reasoning why this happens. Can someone explain in detail what's going on here?

What happens when a parent record is deleted in the Parent Child model having a Lookup Relationship between Parent - Child Objects?

source: http://www.allaboutsfdc.com/dev-401-quiz-part-1-q9.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lookup is a reference on one object to another object, although you could call the referred object the parent and referring one the child, the relationship can be deleted and changed.

A master-detail relationship is a stricter relationship, where the children (detail records) are tied to the parent (master). They can't be moved to another master (yet - this is coming soon) and deleting the master will delete all of it's children.

Best bet when establishing a schema is to always create relationships as a lookup first, as you can convert them to Master Detail relationships when required, but you can't go back the other way.

Thus to answer the question: since the question says **Lookup** *and not* **Master Detail** the children would not be deleted so the answer here is **D**.

Comment: Got it. I think the break down was that I didn't realise that you can call the 2 objects in a lookup relationship a parent = child. Thanks guys.

Comment: Objects can now be re-mastered.  You have to enable this via a field setting.

Comment: Also, you can go from master-detail back to lookup as long as you don't have features (i.e. rollups or cross-object workflows) that depend on the master detail relationship.

Comment: That's true, as of the latest release you can now change them back.

Answer (score 1):

For Salesforce, if the relationship is a Master/Detail, the child will be deleted when the parent is deleted.  If the relationship is a lookup, the child will NOT be deleted when the parent is deleted.

Comment: Can you clarify what a lookup relationship is in a master-detail relationship?  I thought since the objects are parent child- this turns into a Master child. Thanks Ralph!